# Where can I use @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Can someone explain me why this will work:

```
@Transactional
@Test
public void test() {
    save();
}
public void save() {
    Scenario scenar = new Scenario();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(scenar);
}
```

And this won't, because it won't find a transaction:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    save();
}
@Transactional
public void save() {
    Scenario scenar = new Scenario();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(scenar);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think it's because you are using an internal method that is marked as `@Transactional`, It means that `@Transactional` has no effect because that method is not proxied by spring because it's not marked as `@Test`.

Comment: it will not commit your transaction! its a good practice to use in your tests,  because you can test your save method and keep your database clean, to not break another tests using the same database.

Answer (score 2):

Spring @Transactional annotation works using Spring AOP. This means, that when a bean that contains a method with that annotation is injected as a dependency for a different bean, it gets wrapped in a proxy. This proxy has the same interface as the bean, but performs additional actions before a method is invoked (wrapping it in a transaction in this case). You can think of it as a sort of a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You can even see the proxy being invoked when you debug your application.

Now, when the method that you annotate with @Transactional is called from the same class, there is no (at least, no easy) way to inject the proxy. There just isn't a way to replace the object referenced by the "this" keyword in Java.

[More reading on Spring AOP proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

Comment: That would be the correct answer ... outside a test :-)

Comment: Actually, I think SpringJUnit4ClassRunner builds a Spring context. I think it also retrieves tests as beans from it. Even if not, the behaviour is actually not that different :)

Answer (score 2):

As you have a method annotated as `@Test` I assume this is part of a Junit Test class.

Spring developpers know that test methods usually do not implement interfaces, and as such cannot support JDK proxying. So they specially support `@Transactional` annotation **on a `@Test` method**. The [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx) says :

#### *Enabling and disabling transactions*

*Annotating a test method with `@Transactional` causes the test to be run within a transaction that will, by default, be automatically rolled back after completion of the test. If a test class is annotated with `@Transactional`, each test method within that class hierarchy will be run within a transaction. Test methods that are not annotated with `@Transactional` (at the class or method level) will not be run within a transaction. Furthermore, tests that are annotated with `@Transactional` but have the propagation type set to NOT_SUPPORTED will not be run within a transaction.*